# FluentAssertions, making sure IEnumerable contains only single element

Tags: c#, xunit, fluent-assertions

I am writing unit tests and I have something that looks like this:

```
[Fact]
public void GetFoos_only_gets_foo1()
{
    _foo1.included = true; //Foo object
    _foo2.included = false; //Foo object
    _sut.GetFoos().Should().OnlyContain(_foo1); // this doesn't work, is there a specific syntax to use?
}
```

And `GetFoos()` returns and `IEnumerable<Foo>`

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Please clarify the question

Answer (score 7):

OnlyContain expects a predicate -

```
 GetFoos().Should().OnlyContain(x => _foo1.Equals(x));
```

Answer (score 4):

With 6.7.0 version of FluentAssertions you can use :

```
_sut.GetFoos()
    .Should().ContainSingle()
    .Which.Should().Be(_foo1);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this page as see if it helps. https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki

```
collection.Should().ContainSingle();
collection.Should().ContainSingle(x => x > 3);
collection.Should().Contain(8).And.HaveElementAt(2, 5).And.NotBeSubsetOf(new[] {11, 56});
collection.Should().Contain(x => x > 3); 
collection.Should().Contain(collection, 5, 6); // It should contain the original items, plus 5 and 6.
```

Comment: This doesn't directly address the question.

Comment: It shows different ways of getting results without giving the answer directly. Thanks for the down vote. Much appreciated.

Comment: Im serious though, maybe I should have been more specific.

Comment: @EricBowser your answer was good but you need to add an explanation for the uninitiated just a quick one liner explaining what one or more of those lines are doing would have been great (sort that and I will up vote you buddy)