# FluentAssertions: check a list contains an object, excluding a property

Tags: .net, fluent-assertions

I have several Event classes which implement IEvent.
To check actual event against expected event I use

```
actualEvent.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedEvent,opt => opt.RespectingRuntimeTypes()
                                                         .Excluding(e => e.DateCreated));
```

The events have a DateCreated property which I ignore as the actual and expected are created at different times.

How do I check if expectedEvent exists at least once in a list of actualEvents?

I would like to do the following;

```
actualEvents.Should().Contain(expectedEvent,opt => opt.RespectingRuntimeTypes()
                                                      .Excluding(e => e.DateCreated));
```

but it is not possible.

Can this be done in fluentassertions?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar scenario where I had a list of items (an object with properties) and I wanted to check if the list contained a local item I was testing for.

I found the solution on this question: [FluentAssertions, making sure IEnumerable contains only single element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525434/fluentassertions-making-sure-ienumerable-contains-only-single-element)

I simplified my solution by writing the following statement:

```
FooList.Should().Contain(fooItem, x => true)
```

The above constraint states the FooList object should contain the fooItem this is expressed with the lambda x => true.

Fairly straight forward and worked for my use case. Give it a try and check out that question thread I linked it may help.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using FluentAssertions 4.19.4, I solved the problem by implementing my own extension method.

Each element in the collection is asserted individually against the expected element, using the **ShouldBeEquivalentTo** method which can accept the config argument.

```
using FluentAssertions.Collections;
using FluentAssertions.Equivalency;
using FluentAssertions.Execution;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace FluentAssertions.Extensions
{
    public static class FluentAssertionsHelper
    {
        public static AndWhichConstraint<TAssertions, T> Contain<TAssertions, T>(this SelfReferencingCollectionAssertions<T, TAssertions> colAssert,
            T expected,
            Func<EquivalencyAssertionOptions<T>, EquivalencyAssertionOptions<T>> config,
            string because = "",
            params object[] becauseArgs) where TAssertions : SelfReferencingCollectionAssertions<T, TAssertions>
        {
            var items = colAssert.Subject;

            if (items == null)
            {
                Execute.Assertion.BecauseOf(because, becauseArgs).FailWith("Expected {context:collection} to contain {0}{reason}, but found {1}.", expected, items);
            }

            var containsItem = false;

            using (var scope = new AssertionScope())
            {
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        item.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expected, config, because, becauseArgs);
                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException) { }

                    var failures = scope.Discard();
                    if (!failures.Any())
                    {
                        containsItem = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!containsItem)
            {
                Execute.Assertion.BecauseOf(because, becauseArgs).FailWith("Expected {context:collection} {0} to contain {1}{reason}.", items, expected);
            }

            return new AndWhichConstraint<TAssertions, T>((TAssertions)colAssert, items.Where(item => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(item, expected)));
        }
    }
}
```

You can then write the following:

```
using FluentAssertions;
using FluentAssertions.Extensions;

collection.Should().Contain(item, config => config.Excluding(item => item.MyProperty));
```